# Custom Iterator with a callback

Tags: php, symfony

For my project, I have a DoctrineIterator created by a repository.
This iterator returns an array based on my internal request.

I need

- another iterator
- returning an object based on this array
- a generic solution (I have more than one occurrence of this)

The usage of the second iterator is out of my scope, so a can't update the value it returns.

I thought a could create a custom Iterator with a callback to update each item

```
class CallbackIterator extends \IteratorIterator
{
    private $callback;

    public function __construct(Traversable $iterator, callable $callback)
    {
        $this->callback = $callback;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return call_user_func($this->callback, parent::current());
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I'm surprised there isn't any iterator of this kind [in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

I may go in the wrong direction, what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you can use custom iterator (`OuterIterator`) and process cursor on inner iterator but get element with you callable.

See:

```
<?php

$arrayIterator = new \ArrayIterator([
    [
        'id'   => 1,
        'name' => 'John Smith',
    ],
    [
        'id'   => 2,
        'name' => 'Julia Robin',
    ],
]);

class CallableIterator implements \Iterator
{
    private \Iterator $innerIterator;
    private \Closure $callback;

    public function __construct(\Iterator $innerIterator, \Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->innerIterator = $innerIterator;
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $currentElement = $this->innerIterator->current();

        return \call_user_func($this->callback, $currentElement);
    }

    public function next(): void
    {
        $this->innerIterator->next();
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->innerIterator->key();
    }

    public function valid(): bool
    {
        return $this->innerIterator->valid();
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        $this->innerIterator->rewind();
    }
}


$myIterator = new CallableIterator($arrayIterator, static function (array $element) {
    $element['hash'] = \md5($element['name']);

    return $element;
});

print_r(\iterator_to_array($myIterator));
```

In this solution we rewrite result element and add hash based on `md5` of name. But in you case, you can add any logic to you callable (create new object, remove specific element, add new element to array, etc...).

`Iterator` in Doctrine implement `Iterator` interface, as result you can use this solution in you problem.

P.S. If we use inner iterator - the best practice implement `OuterIterator` in our iterator. Because many system can read inner iterator and you speak for all next code: `I am a parent iterator and can change inner result`.